# Cannot overwrite Django authentication templates in AWS

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-authentication, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have developped a Django application and I have been using the django-authtools module to be able to login using email. It is working great on my laptop but when I tried to deploy it in production in AWS using Beanstalk, it seems Django does not recognize the overwrite of the authentication module and is forcing redirection to the django built-in authentication module. Everything else seems to work fine (from a deployment and application point of view).
It results in a 500 error:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (-) - - [04/Jul/2017:19:07:54 +1000] "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 7807 "http://<removed>.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"

    Internal Server Error: /accounts/login/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
        response = response.render()
      File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
        self.content = self.rendered_content
      File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 82, in rendered_content
        template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
      File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 64, in resolve_template
        return select_template(template, using=self.using)
      File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 53, in select_template
        raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
    django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: registration/login.html
```

Again this is working perfectly fine on my laptop, but not on the AWS server. I cannot find any difference between the 2 and they are running same version of django and django-authools:

```
$ pip freeze

[...]
Django==1.11.2
django-authtools==1.5.0
django-extensions==1.7.6
django-phonenumber-field==1.3.0
django-qsstats-magic==0.7.2
django-simple-captcha==0.5.5
django-storages==1.6.1
[...]
```

The only difference seems to be the version of python, 3.4.3 on AWS and 3.5.2 on my laptop.

On the server, my settings.py file is the same as on my laptop:

myproject/settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
    'authtools',
    'captcha',
    'storages',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'django_extensions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "authtools.User"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
```

},
]

myapp/urls.py:

```
from authtools import urls
[...]
    url(r'^accounts/', include('authtools.urls')),
[...]
```

authtools/url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from authtools import views as authools_views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', authools_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', authools_views.LogoutView.as_view(), {'next_page': '/accounts/login'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^password_change/$', authools_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    url(r'^password_change/done/$', authools_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', authools_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', authools_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', authools_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13})-(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        authools_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view()),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        authools_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```

I have also tried to pass the template in the url statement directly (LoginView.as_view(template_name='myapp/login.html')) but same result.

Extract of authtools/view.py:

```
class LoginView(AuthDecoratorsMixin, WithCurrentSiteMixin, WithNextUrlMixin, FormView):
    print('ENTERING LOGIN VIEW')
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'myapp/login.html'
    allow_authenticated = True
    success_url = resolve_url_lazy(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

    # BBB: This is deprecated (See LoginView.get_allow_authenticated)
    disallow_authenticated = None
```

The template showed in the error "registration/login.html" is the built-in template and not the one provided by the authtools module which should overwrite it. 
Also when navigating to the /admin/ of my website, I can login correctly with my super user and when going back to the site I am then detected as being authenticated. The logout action though redirects me to the default logout page and is not using my custom template provided in the authtools module (so same behavior).

If any one would have a solution or any idea of where to investigate that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

I am adding my beanstalk config file just in case it helps, even though I don't believe this is a problem related to beanstalk itself.

```
.ebextensions# cat 001_set_env.config 
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    PYTHONPATH: /opt/python/current/app/myapp:/opt/python/current/app/authtools:$PYTHONPATH
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "myproject/wsgi.py"
.ebextensions# cat 002_deploy.config 
commands:
  01_update_pip:
    command: "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip"
  02_set_time_zone:
    command: ln -f -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Sydney /etc/localtime

container_commands:
  01_makemigration:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py makemigrations --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  03_initialize_db:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py initializedb"
    leader_only: true
  04_create_superuser:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true
```

Comment: Please show your `TEMPLATES` setting.

Comment: I've added it. Let me know if you need something else. Thanks!

Comment: `['templates']` looks wrong. Where is the actual template that you want to use located? What is the `LoginView` that you have posted - is it from your own app, or have you edited the code from `authtools`?

Comment: The template I want to use is located in `myapp/templates/myapp/login.html` . In that case I am importing the urls of the module authtools which refer to its own views.py file, which I have provided above. In this authtools views.py, I have modified the variable template_name to point to the templates in my main app `template_name = 'myapp/login.html'`. If django had a problem to find this custom template, wouldn't it raise an error saying this, instead of trying to locate the default template (registration/login.html)?

Comment: As you say, if the missing template is `registration/login.html`, then it looks as if your customised `LoginView` is not being run. I would avoid editing files from external packages like `authtools`, it makes it very confusing. Are you making lots of changes, or only trying to change the template name?

Comment: I have only changed the template name. I have also tried to modify it in the urls.py when calling the view but result is the same. It seems the view is not being run as you say but I'm not sure how to diagnose or investigate this. Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I have finally found the issue to this problem. I had the authools module installed both in site_packages and locally in my project. On my local laptop, it seems the order of precedence was looking at my local django project first (where I had the module with the right template paths), whereas on AWS, the python path order listed site_packages first, thus looking into an unmodified version of authtools.
I have therefore removed the authtools version installed in my project and I am now using the original version installed in site_packages, while over-writting the authools template names in my app urls.py directly.

Thank you all for helping and putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you stop editing the code in `authtools`. It is not clear how you are doing it, and since the error is showing the missing template is `registration/login.html`, it is now working in production.

If you rename your template from `myapp/templates/myapp/login.html` to `myapp/templates/registration/login.html`, then the app directories loader should find your template.

Finally, as an aside, your `DIRS` setting looks incorrect.

```
'DIRS': ['templates'],
```

If you want to include a `myproject/templates` directory, then change it to

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```